# Display in SQL query is not working

Tags: php, mysql

Here I Am Going to display the bookrentalinfo table records which must be borrowed and to be returned by field(renewaldate) must be less than currentdate.
But here i not be able to display those record which has to be returned by field less than current date, can u please suggest where i need to place this condition to work properly, thank you in advance.

My file mail.php

```
<?php


include('db/db.php');
include('assets/page_header.php');
?>

<?php

$currentdate=date("H:i:s");
echo $currentdate;

$str="select * from bookrentalinfo where status='BORROWED'   ";
$query=mysql_query($str);


echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>BookId</th><th>MemNo</th><th>RentedOn</th><th>ToBeReturnedBy</th><th>ActualReturnDate</th><th>Status</th></tr>";
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    if($res['tobereturnedby']<=$currentdate)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$res['bookid']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['memno']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['rentedon']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['tobereturnedby']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['actualreturndate']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['status']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: What is the format of the `$res['tobereturnedby']` variable that is returned from the database?

Comment: Sir, timestamp format

Comment: `mysql_query` `mysql_fetch_array` has been deprecated. Use `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_fetch_array` instead

Comment: Ok sir..........

Comment: @Vradhit Do you mean Unix timestamp format?

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp formats probably aren't matching, so the comparison in your if statement isn't filtering correctly.  Fixing this depends on what is being returned from your query:

- If `$res['tobereturnedby']` returns a [**UNIX timestamp**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), then set your `$currentdate` to one as well:

  ```
  $currentdate = time();
  ```
- If `$res['tobereturnedby']` returns a [**MySQL timestamp**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), then set your `$currentdate` to something that matches:

  ```
  $currentdate = date('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
  ```

  **NOTE:** In this case you should strip all non-numerical characters from both of your comparison values before the comparison takes place.  You can use either [`filter_val()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) or [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to do so.